# Is there any way to dry out this generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator, dry

The following method is in my class and tries to prime itself before gettings its work done. The primer is at lazy at doing its work as the processing loop that follows it. Five lines are repeated in these two loops, and it is not obvious to me what the best approach to eliminating the repetition might be.

```
@classmethod
def __get_start_words(cls, iterable, n, start_words):
    iterator, buffer, sentinel = iter(iterable), Deque(maxlen=n), object()
    for _ in range(n):
        item = next(iterator, sentinel)
        if item is sentinel:
            # raise ValueError('iterable was too short to satisfy n')
            break
        buffer.append(item)
        yield item
    start_words[buffer.prefix] += 1
    while True:
        if buffer[0][-1] in cls.TERMINATORS:
            start_words[buffer.suffix] += 1
        item = next(iterator, sentinel)
        if item is sentinel:
            break
        buffer.append(item)
        yield item
```

Is there an effective and clear way of writing those last five lines just once in the class or method?

---

**Addendum**

In answer to the question regarding what `prefix` and `suffix` are, here is the `Deque` class:

```
class Deque(collections.deque):
    """Deque([iterable[, maxlen]]) -> Deque instance"""

    @property
    def prefix(self):
        """Property allowing capture of all but last item in deque."""
        item = self.pop()
        value = tuple(self)
        self.append(item)
        return value

    @property
    def suffix(self):
        """Property allowing capture of all but first item in deque."""
        item = self.popleft()
        value = tuple(self)
        self.appendleft(item)
        return value
```

---

**Second Version**

After taking into account what others had to say, the following method was written for efficiency:

```
@classmethod
def __get_start_words(cls, iterable, n, start_words):
    iterator, buffer, count = iter(iterable), Deque(maxlen=n), 0
    for item, count in zip(iterator, range(n)):
        buffer.append(item)
        yield item
    if count + 1 < n:
        raise ValueError('iterable was too short to satisfy n')
    start_words[buffer.prefix] += 1
    try:
        while True:
            if buffer[0][-1] in cls.TERMINATORS:
                start_words[buffer.suffix] += 1
            item = next(iterator)
            buffer.append(item)
            yield item
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

---

**Third Version**

This third version of the method has been adapted from [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3555845/daniel)'s insightful answer:

```
@classmethod
def __get_start_words(cls, iterable, n, start_words):
    count, buffer = 0, Deque(maxlen=n)
    for count, item in enumerate(iterable, 1):
        yield item
        buffer.append(item)
        if count == n:
            start_words[buffer.prefix] += 1
        if count >= n and buffer[0][-1] in cls.TERMINATORS:
            start_words[buffer.suffix] += 1
    if count < n:
        raise ValueError('iterable was too short to satisfy n')
```

---

**Final Version**

This method is significantly better than my first version -- thanks to the people who helped me here.

```
@classmethod
def __get_start_words(cls, iterable, n, start_words):
    buffer = Deque(maxlen=n)
    for count, item in enumerate(iterable, 1):
        yield item
        buffer.append(item)
        if count == n:
            start_words[buffer.prefix] += 1
        if count >= n and buffer[0][-1] in cls.TERMINATORS:
            start_words[buffer.suffix] += 1
    if len(buffer) < n:
        raise ValueError('iterable was too short to satisfy n')
```

Comment: btw, what is `buffer.prefix` and `buffer.suffix`?

Comment: I decided to make a logic check in the first loop by raising an exception if appropriate. If the change invalidates the question, I will happily delete it.

Comment: probably a better question for SE: codereview

Comment: Why isn't your for loop just `for item in iterable:`?

Comment: @RobertB I thought it would be better to make the primer and processor clearly separate from each other.

Comment: So in your second loop, just loop over the iterable, no need for a while and a sentinel, right?

Comment: @RobertB You are almost right there. The first two lines of the second loop always run, including once after the iterator has been exhausted.

Comment: for future reference... Using `next()` inside a `try: .... catch StopIteration: ... ` block is faster than using a sentinel. It isn't really needed in this case as per Daniel's answer, but it does sometimes come in handy

Comment: @Aaron Is the second version of the method any better?

Comment: @NoctisSkytower to be frank... no. Keep as little as possible inside try catch statements as a general rule. I would keep only the call to next() and a break if stop iteration is thrown inside the block: `try: item = next except StopIteration: break`

Comment: It's not entirely clear what this generator actually does; what does the input look like, and what is the logic behind what what `start_words` is and how it evolves?

Comment: Last comment, a `for` loop can have an `else`. The `else` is only executed if the loop exits normally. If you `break` out of the for loop, the else does not execute. So you don't need to test anything coming out of your for loop. You just need an "else" that raises an exception because if it were long enough, you would have hit a "break".

Comment: @chepner The code was helpful during the implementation of [Mark V. Shaney](https://pastebin.com/DrWczyrT) in contemporary Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `for`-loop:

```
@classmethod
def __get_start_words(cls, iterable, n, start_words):
    buffer = Deque(maxlen=n)
    for idx, item in enumerate(iterable, 1):
        buffer.append(item)
        yield item
        if idx == n:
            start_words[buffer.prefix] += 1
        if idx >= n and buffer[0][-1] in cls.TERMINATORS:
            start_words[buffer.suffix] += 1
    if len(buffer) < n:
        raise ValueError('iterable was too short to satisfy n')
```

Some thoughts on your second version: `count` is not necessary when using `islice`:

```
for item in islice(iterator, n):
    buffer.append(item)
    yield item
if len(buffer) < n:
    raise ValueError('iterable was too short to satisfy n')
```

Further refactoring leading to:

```
@classmethod
def __get_start_words(cls, iterable, n, start_words):
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    buffer = deque(islice(iterable, n-1))
    yield from buffer
    if len(buffer) < n - 1:
        raise ValueError('iterable was too short to satisfy n')
    start_words[tuple(buffer)] += 1
    for item in iterable:
        buffer.append(item)
        yield item
        first = buffer.popleft()
        if first[-1] in cls.TERMINATORS:
            start_words[tuple(buffer)] += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! After looking at the code, I realized some error checking should be done and changed the first loop by raising an exception instead of breaking. Would you mind adapting your already well-written answer for the exceptional case?

Comment: If you think that there is no reason to change my code for improvements since it was modified to raise an exception (no reason to dry it out), please let me know, and I will revert the code to use `break` instead of `raise` as it was before.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower this is basically how I'd approach it. It looked like you were just trying to replicate for loops with a custom `raise StopIteration` approach

Comment: Doesn't your solution have a problem with the last two lines of your `for` loop? The first two lines of my second `while` loop run once more after the iterator is exhausted. Your loop does not appear to do the same.

Comment: So there is no need for the second version of my method that was added at the end of the question? I think I am beginning to understand how those last two processing lines in your loop execute exactly like mine. What was confusing me was the fact they got moved; but functionally, they still get executed like as before.

Comment: Oh, it does appear that you need to change `for idx, item in enumerate(iterable):` so that it uses a different start: `for idx, item in enumerate(iterable, 1):` You may also want to change `buffer = Deque(maxlen=n)` to instead be `buffer, idx = Deque(maxlen=n), 0`.

Comment: If my corrections are valid and you make the needed changes to your code, your answer looks like it would be good enough to accept as the correct answer. The third version of my method shown in the question may help.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower It this answer gave you a solution, you may edit it, you may accept it too. This way you will help other readers that have the same question.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower: you're right with the wrong starting index. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for your great help! The only thing I changed in my final version is swapping the lines that add the item to the buffer and yielding the item.